# Python OpenCV Hough Circle taking a long time to load an image from webcamera

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am trying to take a video stream, from a web camera and detect circles in it using `HoughCircles()`. But when ever I try to run the code the video takes along time to load the image, or wont load the image at all. Any help on how to get the code to do circle detection would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm not trying to do anything real time. I just want to get some basic circle detection to work on a video stream from my web camera.

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = 320
height = 240
dim = (width, height)
while(True):
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),5)
    resized = cv2.resize(gray,dim,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200)
    circ = cv2.HoughCircles(resized,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,30,param1=50,param2=75,
                              minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
    cv2.imshow('video',resized)
    if circ is not None:
        circ = np.uint16(np.around(circ))[0,:]
        print(circ)
        for j in circ:
            cv2.circle(resized, (j[0], j[1]), j[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('video',resized)
        if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:# esc Key
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Again thanks for any help.

Comment: Try resizing the images to some smaller dimensions and then apply processing on it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just messed around with the parameters in `HoughCircles` for a bit and it worked. Resizing it from 640X480 to 320X240 significantly improved the frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've Figured it out. I had to reduce mess around with the parameters in `HoughCircles`. I've changed

```
circ = cv2.HoughCircles(resized,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,30,param1=50,param2=75, minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

to

```
cv2.HoughCircles(resized,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,param1=50,param2=35, minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

This allows the code to display the video stream while detecting circles at a reasonable frame rate. Also thanks @ZdaR for the help.

Here's the code that works

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import serial

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
width = 320
height = 240
dim = (width, height)
while(True):
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),5)
    resized = cv2.resize(gray,dim,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    circ = cv2.HoughCircles(resized,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,param1=50,param2=35,
                              minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
    cv2.imshow('video',resized)
    if circ is not None:
        circ = np.uint16(np.around(circ))[0,:]
        print(circ)
        for j in circ:
            cv2.circle(resized, (j[0], j[1]), j[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)  
        cv2.imshow('video',resized)
        if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:# esc Key
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```